# How do I achieve a count for regions in a sub menu of categories using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, parent-child, eager-loading, submenu

I’m trying to get a count of listings in regions under a category.

The menu for regions on the home page shows a count of all listings in their regions from every category.
On the categories page I’m trying to show a count for regions, that have listings in a selected category.

In my Listing Model

```
 public function scopeInCategory($query, Category $category)
 {
    return $query->whereIn('category_id', [$category->id]);
 }

 public function region()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(Region::class);
 }
```

In my Region model

```
 public function listings()
 {
    return $this->hasMany(Listing::class);
 }
```

In my CategoryController

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Category $category)
    {

        $regions = Region::with(['listings' => function($query) use ($category) {
        
            $query->inCategory($category);
        }])->first('region')->get();

       return view('categories.index', compact('regions'));
   }
}
```

and in my region_dropdown.blade.php

```
 @foreach($regions as $region)
   
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ $region->name }} 
    ( {{ $region->listings->count() }} )</a>
     
 @endforeach
```

But this is not working the region menu still shows a count of all listings in every category on the categories page.

Comment: You have `use ($category)` but I don't see any variable called `$category` in the `index` function ?!

Comment: yes you're right, I've modified it to Category $category, but it's still not working.

Comment: Yes obviously it won't magically work it was just a typo. Anyway, do you have a relation between the `Region` and `Listing` models that is already present on both models ? Based on the look of your question, a `Has Many` relation (a `Region` has many `Listing`s) should be present. If you have set up a relation between the models, kindly add the respective code portions to your question.

Comment: Yep I have a HasMany and belongsTo relationship between my Region and Listing model. I’ll add this bit of code to include it in the question.

Comment: I just posted an answer that might help you, please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eloquent's `withCount` method to get a count of `Listing`s under each `Region` by a specific `Category` and then access the `count`ed value on each `Region` by accessing the `listings_count` attribute that Eloquent will initialize for you.

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Category $category)
    {
       $regions = Region::withCount([
           'listings' => fn($q) => $q->where('category_id', $category->id)
       ])->get();
       return view('categories.index', compact('regions'));
   }
}
```

And in your `blade` file:

```
@foreach($regions as $region)
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        {{ sprintf('%s (%d)', $region->name, $region->listings_count) }}
    </a>
@endforeach
```

Feel free to ask for any clarification.